# How to compose a types from larger type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Say I defined a global state's type with:

```
export interface State {
  user: {
    name: string
  }
  auth: {
    loggedIn: boolean
  }
}
```

Now I want to define some sub-type with

```
interface Props {
  name: State.user.name
  loggedIn: State.auth.loggedIn
}
// and then use it with
export const MyComponent = connect < Props > // ...
```

Is this possible ? Is there another way to ensure that if the state architecture changes in State, I get errors or new types in Props ?

(of course the State is much more complex then shown here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) on types to get [lookup types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) of properties:

```
interface Props {
  name: State['user']['name']
  loggedIn: State['auth']['loggedIn']
}
```

Dot notation (the first thing you tried) doesn't work on types in TypeScript, at least as of 2.4.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution:

```
let state: State
interface Props {
  name: typeof state.user.name
  loggedIn: typeof state.auth.loggedIn
}
```

But maybe there is a better solution ?